# android sending files over whatsapp and specify app for opening

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

Is it possible to send files over WhatsApp, Telegram etc. and specify the app for opening it, programmatically?

To be more precise: I want to send some music files from my own app over some instant messangers like WhatsApp, BUT on the same time, I want to provide information about the my app and specify, that the sound should be played with my own app. If it's not installed on the other side, the user should get the option to download the app.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps a custom file type? But I don't think you can make android recommend your app to open the file.

Comment: check here. you probably want to setup an intent filter and url scheme.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: Nope. You can't do that. But you can send a download link for your app or a link that's meant to be opened in it, which transfers the file.

Comment: you want to send a file through a third-party app, while telling the recipient third-party app how they should handle the file?

Comment: @njzk2: yes, exactly.
well, if it's not possible, can you at least send code, which checks whether my app is installed or not?

Comment: @njzk2 - that is precisely what meta data like mime types is intended to do, though I don't know if it will work in this case (and not for the installing if not already present case)

Comment: Ok, to make it a bit more easy: is it possible to send an intent to start a certain view of my app and perform a certain action?